# asynchronous web Api call success function not returning the data Set

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

my asynchronous web API returning the data

```
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("PrjID_SelectMob")]
  public async Task<List<PrjID_SelectMob>> PrjID_SelectMob(int CKy, int UsrKy, int ObjKy, int TrnTypKy, int PreKy, string EnvironmentName)
  {
        List<PrjID_SelectMob> objMasList = await accMasService.PrjID_SelectMob(CKy, UsrKy, ObjKy, TrnTypKy, PreKy, EnvironmentName);
        return objMasList;
  }
```

ajax success function not getting the return data i will get (dataset = undefined)

```
   $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:49558/api/ComboLoad/PrjID_SelectMob?CKy=" + Cky + "&UsrKy=" + userky + "&ObjKy=" + ObjKy + "&TrnTypKy=" + FormGlblData.TrnTypKy + "&PreKy=" + 1 + "&EnvironmentName=" + Envermentname,
    type:'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (dataSource) {
        dataset = dataSource;
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus);
        alert("Status: " + textStatus);
        alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
    }
```

});

I will get this error

```
Status: parsererror
```

Error: Error: jQuery112303621583680685383_1530522960313 was not called

How can i bind the dataset into Success Function

Comment: did u tried using `dataType: 'json',` instead `dataType: 'jsonp',`

Comment: yes i tried dataType :'json' and i get access-control-allow-origin  header  After that i use  dataType :'jsonp' NithinChandran

Comment: did the web api method getting fired? u tested using breakpoints

Comment: ok i think you are using jsonp for allowing cross domain request. but in fact you are not sending actual jsonp object from server, it still a json object. you have to enable CORS in the server

Comment: Ya It's hit the API Controller And Return the data Set

Comment: yea i enable the CORS in API

Comment: Dubble check that your api really return json. Most likely its returning xml and thats why you get a parse error

Comment: i check API returning List Of project and i convert into Json

Comment: no improvement after converting into json